# Optimize multiple window.location.href = "index.html"

Tags: javascript

I have multiples IDs in my HTML. When I click that element (.onclick) I want to redirect them all (window.location.href) to the same site.

So far I have tried this code but doesn't works:

```
document.getElementById("boxed", "inmerse", "flow", "scape", "fierce", "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"
```

This is the code that works

```
document.getElementById("boxed").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"

document.getElementById("immerse").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("flow").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("scape").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("fierce").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("name6").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("name7").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("name8").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"


document.getElementById("name9").onclick = () => window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"
```

I'm expecting to create some function or another way to optimize the code.

Comment: for loop over the array and bind the events

Comment: Why don't you just make the relevant DOM nodes anchor tags? Why do you need Javascript at all?

Comment: Maybe you should read about HTML classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all of the elements a class

e.g.

```
<button id="boxed" class="ClassName"></button>
<button id="flow" class="ClassName"></button>
```

Then use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = "../3infoCardPremium/3infoCardPremium.html"
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed, `getElementsByClassName("ClassName")` returns an `array`

Comment: Thanks, @Xander code is working, much better for eyes of everyone =)